# Connect docker container

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-compose

I´ve been looking in google but i cannot find any answer.

It is possible connect to a virtualbox docker container that I just start up. I have the IP of the virtual machine, but if I try to connect by SSH of course ask me for a password.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see 
https://github.com/BITPlan/docker-stackoverflowanswers/tree/master/33232371

to repeat steps.

On my Mac OS X machine

```
docker-machine env default
```

shows

```
 export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"
```

So i added an entry

```
192.168.99.100 docker
```

to my /etc/hosts

so that ping docker works.
As a Dockerfile i am using:

```
# Ubuntu image
FROM ubuntu:14.04
```

which I am building with

```
docker build -t bitplan/sshtest:0.0.1 .
```

and testing with

```
docker run -it bitplan/sshtest:0.0.1 /bin/bash
```

Now ssh docker will react with

```
The authenticity of host 'docker (192.168.99.100)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:osRuE6B8bCIGiL18uBBrtySH5+iGPkiHHiq5PZNfDmc.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'docker,192.168.99.100' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
wf@docker's password:
```

But here you are connecting to the docker machine not your image!
The ssh port is at port 22. You need to redirect it to another port and configure your image to support ssh to root or a valid user.

See e.g. https://docs.docker.com/examples/running_ssh_service/

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to connect to a running container or trying to connect to the virtualbox image running the docker daemon?

If the first, you cannot just SSH into a running container unless that container is running an ssh daemon. The easiest way to get a shell into a running container is with `docker exec -ti <container name/id> /bin/sh`. Do a `docker ps` to see running containers.

If the second, if your host was created with `docker-machine` then you can ssh into it with `docker-machine ssh <machine name>`. You can see all of you're running machines with `docker-machine ls`.

If this doesn't help can you clarify your question a little and provide details around how your creating your image and starting the container.

Answer (score -1):

You can use ssh keys to access passwordless.

Here's some intro
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_keys